# How can a tag be deleted?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/jesus-predicts-that-some-will-not-die-until-he-comes-again-in-his-kingdom-but-th) had the tag [proficy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proficy) so I retagged it [prophecy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophecy) on the assumption that the original tag was just a misspelling.

Should [proficy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proficy) be made a synonym of [prophecy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophecy) or should it be deleted?

If it should be deleted, how is that done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags with no question will automatically get cleaned up, just give them time.

To delete a tag, remove it from all the posts it was used on.

I don't think tag aliases are needed for normal misspellings, we can just correct these. Users never get tags right anyways. Only particularly onerous ones will need synonyms to save us work.

Comment: Just additional: if there are a *lot* of posts needing it to be edited, there are admin tools to do that much more efficiently, and without taking over the front page (i.e. without "bumping" all the posts affected)